# If value is higher then X for the past 6 months then 1 else 0

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a question. I got a Table with the following

| PersonalNumber | Dim_Date | PercentageCategory |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 20190101 | 0.81 |
| 1 | 20190101 | 0.81 |
| 1 | 20190101 | 0.81 |
| 1 | 20190101 | 0.81 |
| 1 | 20190102 | NULL |
| 1 | 20190103 | NULL |
| 1 | 20190201 | 0.81 |
| 1 | 20190301 | 0.86 |
| 1 | 20190401 | 0.88 |
| 1 | 20190501 | 0.87 |
| 1 | 20190601 | 0.88 |
| 1 | 20190701 | 0.66 |
| 1 | 20190702 | NULL |
| 1 | 20190801 | 0.82 |
| 1 | 20190901 | 0.83 |
| 1 | 20191001 | 0.84 |
| 2 | 20190101 | 0.81 |
| 2 | 20190201 | 0.81 |
| 2 | 20190301 | 0.86 |
| 2 | 20190401 | 0.88 |
| 2 | 20190501 | 0.87 |
| 2 | 20190601 | 0.88 |
| 2 | 20190701 | 0.86 |
| 2 | 20190801 | 0.82 |
| 2 | 20190901 | 0.83 |
| 2 | 20191001 | 0.84 |

What I would like to add is an column who looks at the percentage of the past 6 months where the percentage is consecutively is higher then 0.80. If yes, then it gets an 1 else 0.

Outcome

| PersonalNumber | Dim_Date | PercentageCategory | NEWCOLUMN |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 20190101 | 0.81 | 0 |
| 1 | 20190101 | 0.81 | 0 |
| 1 | 20190101 | 0.81 | 0 |
| 1 | 20190101 | 0.81 | 0 |
| 1 | 20190102 | NULL | 0 |
| 1 | 20190103 | NULL | 0 |
| 1 | 20190201 | 0.81 | 0 |
| 1 | 20190301 | 0.86 | 0 |
| 1 | 20190401 | 0.88 | 0 |
| 1 | 20190501 | 0.87 | 0 |
| 1 | 20190601 | 0.88 | 0 |
| 1 | 20190701 | 0.66 | 1 |
| 1 | 20190701 | 0.66 | 1 |
| 1 | 20190701 | 0.66 | 1 |
| 1 | 20190701 | 0.66 | 1 |
| 1 | 20190702 | NULL | 0 |
| 1 | 20190801 | 0.82 | 0 |
| 1 | 20190901 | 0.83 | 0 |
| 1 | 20191001 | 0.84 | 0 |
| 2 | 20190101 | 0.81 | 0 |
| 2 | 20190201 | 0.81 | 0 |
| 2 | 20190301 | 0.86 | 0 |
| 2 | 20190401 | 0.88 | 0 |
| 2 | 20190501 | 0.87 | 0 |
| 2 | 20190601 | 0.88 | 0 |
| 2 | 20190701 | 0.86 | 1 |
| 2 | 20190801 | 0.82 | 1 |
| 2 | 20190901 | 0.83 | 1 |
| 2 | 20191001 | 0.84 | 1 |

In my example July 0f 2019 gets an 1 for the client number 1, because the past 6 months every month the percentage was higher then 0.80. For august it gets an 0, because July had an percentage lower than 0.80.

I couldn't find any information on stackoverflow about a similar problem or I couldn't convert the solution from them to my example. If someone could help me, that would be gladly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have exactly one row per month, are there any gaps or multiple per month?

Comment: I have a table which has the days between the start- and end date of a contract. So if client has start date 2019-01-01 and end date is 2020-10-01  --> then the table also has 20190102, 20190103 etc. But the percentagecategory column is always defined on the first of every month

Comment: Why don't the rows for `1,   20190801` `1,  20190901` `1,  20191001` also get a `1`? Ah, I missed *consecutive*, is that right?

Comment: Yeah. the past 6 months of the month you are in, needs to have consecutive percentage of above 0.80

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution assumes that any date having the day part > 1 have NULLs in the percentage column. Also my result does not create new duplicate columns as in your example where July occurs 4 times in the result but only once in the input data.

I called your table `t`:

```sql
SELECT 
  PersonalNumber,
  Dim_Date,
  PercentageCategory,
  CASE WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*)
   FROM 
       (SELECT DISTINCT * FROM t) b
   WHERE
       b.PersonalNumber = a.PersonalNumber AND      
       b.Dim_Date >= DateAdd(m, -6, a.Dim_Date) AND b.Dim_Date < a.Dim_Date AND
       b.PercentageCategory > 0.8
  ) = 6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS NewColumn
FROM t a
```

I used `SELECT DISTINCT * FROM t` in the inner most SELECT. This works only if you have shown us all the columns. If the table has more columns, then you must change this to `SELECT DISTINCT PersonalNumber, Dim_Date, PercentageCategory FROM t`.

See: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/796ab/7

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE Junk (
    PersonalNumber  int   NOT NULL,
    DimDate         date  NOT NULL,
    PercentCategory float NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT Junk_PK PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (PersonalNumber, DimDate)
)

SELECT j.PersonalNumber, j.DimDate, j.PercentCategory,
    CASE
        WHEN m.PercentCategoryMin >= 0.8 AND m.MinDate <= DATEADD(MONTH, -6, j.DimDate)
            THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END AS NewThing
FROM Junk j
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT j.PersonalNumber, j.DimDate, MIN(k.DimDate) AS MinDate, MIN(k.PercentCategory) AS PercentCategoryMin
        FROM Junk j
            INNER JOIN Junk k
                ON j.PersonalNumber = k.PersonalNumber
                AND k.DimDate < j.DimDate
                AND k.DimDate >= DATEADD(MONTH, -6, j.DimDate)
        GROUP BY j.PersonalNumber, j.DimDate
    ) AS m
        ON j.PersonalNumber = m.PersonalNumber AND j.DimDate = m.DimDate
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a bunch of `LAG` window functions. Note that there are no joins here, just a single scan of the base table

```sql
SELECT *,
  NewColumn =
     CASE
        WHEN LAG(t.PercentageCategory, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY t.PersonalNumber ORDER BY t.Dim_Date) > 0.8
         AND LAG(t.PercentageCategory, 2) OVER (PARTITION BY t.PersonalNumber ORDER BY t.Dim_Date) > 0.8
         AND LAG(t.PercentageCategory, 3) OVER (PARTITION BY t.PersonalNumber ORDER BY t.Dim_Date) > 0.8
         AND LAG(t.PercentageCategory, 4) OVER (PARTITION BY t.PersonalNumber ORDER BY t.Dim_Date) > 0.8
         AND LAG(t.PercentageCategory, 5) OVER (PARTITION BY t.PersonalNumber ORDER BY t.Dim_Date) > 0.8
         AND LAG(t.PercentageCategory, 6) OVER (PARTITION BY t.PersonalNumber ORDER BY t.Dim_Date) > 0.8
        THEN 1
        ELSE 0 END
FROM YourTable t
WHERE t.PercentageCategory IS NOT NULL;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=24099db4c7e074bf8953f34441eabe6f)

This assumes, as you say, that there are no gaps or duplicates between rows which have a not-null `PercentageCategory`, otherwise you need to group up the rows, or use a top-1 solution

```sql
SELECT *,
  NewColumn =
     CASE
        WHEN LAG(t.PercentageCategory, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY t.PersonalNumber ORDER BY t.Dim_Date) > 0.8
         AND LAG(t.PercentageCategory, 2) OVER (PARTITION BY t.PersonalNumber ORDER BY t.Dim_Date) > 0.8
         AND LAG(t.PercentageCategory, 3) OVER (PARTITION BY t.PersonalNumber ORDER BY t.Dim_Date) > 0.8
         AND LAG(t.PercentageCategory, 4) OVER (PARTITION BY t.PersonalNumber ORDER BY t.Dim_Date) > 0.8
         AND LAG(t.PercentageCategory, 5) OVER (PARTITION BY t.PersonalNumber ORDER BY t.Dim_Date) > 0.8
         AND LAG(t.PercentageCategory, 6) OVER (PARTITION BY t.PersonalNumber ORDER BY t.Dim_Date) > 0.8
        THEN 1
        ELSE 0 END
FROM (
    SELECT
      t.PersonalNumber,
      t.Dim_Date,
      PercentageCategory = MIN(t.PercentageCategory)
    FROM YourTable t
    WHERE t.PercentageCategory IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY
      t.PersonalNumber,
      t.Dim_Date
) t;
```

Comment: I'm sorry. There could be duplicates with the same PersonalNumber,Dim_Date and PercentageCategory. But that doesnt matter if the LAG function seperates the duplicates on the dim_date column right? For example: I have 3 rows with the same PercentageCategory for Client nr 1 on dim_date 20190101. If the LAG function seperates the PercentageCategory on dim_date --> then every row on 20190101 gets M1 and 20190201 gets M2. I dont want that M2 is for the second row in the table with 20190101. It needs to be the first row in the next month. Im trying to adjust the logic above, but I cant seem to solve

Comment: It works one row at a time, so if you have duplicate rows you will have a problem. Please give a [mcve]

Comment: I edited the original table in my question. Its a table based on day level from the start- and enddate of a client with a contract. But the percentagecategory is defined on the first of every month. There could be duplicate rows on the first of every month for a client with a contract with the same PercentageCategory. But the other columns which makes the difference of the rows is not in the table above. That doesnt matter, thats why I didnt include those columns.

Comment: So is it safe to say that the non-null rows at the beginning of each month are identical? If so then just group it first